# interactive plot geopandas doesn't show

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I have this code from this website:
https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/interactive_mapping.html

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world_filepath = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
world = gpd.read_file(world_filepath)
print(world.head())

world.explore(column='pop_est',cmap='Set2')

plt.show()
```

I try to run the code, the geodataframe data is printed but no plot is shown.
What am i missing?

Thnx in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`world.explore(column='pop_est',cmap='Set2')` should return and display a folium map object so you shouldn't need that `plt.show()` as the bottom.

Also, since you're using an IDE (not jupyter) we need to write the map to disk then open it up in the broswer.

Try

```
import geopandas as gpd
import webbrowser
import os

world_filepath = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
world = gpd.read_file(world_filepath)
print(world.head())

# world.explore() returns a folium map
m = world.explore(column='pop_est',cmap='Set2')

# and then we write the map to disk
m.save('my_map.html')

# then open it
webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('my_map.html'))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Bob, Thanks for the reply! The code runs fine but no plot shows up?

Comment: hmmm, are you using jupyter?

Comment: No. Running python file within PyCharm editor.

Comment: gotcha, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

- `export()` creates a **folium** object, not a **matplotlib** figure
- in **jupyter** just have `m` as last item in code cell
- in other environments you can save as HTML and launch into a browser

```
import geopandas as gpd
import webbrowser
from pathlib import Path

world_filepath = gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
world = gpd.read_file(world_filepath)
print(world.head())

m = world.explore(column='pop_est',cmap='Set2')

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("map.html")
m.save(str(f))
webbrowser.open("file://" + str(f))
```